# Oauth cloning on bitbucket

Tags: heroku, oauth, bitbucket

I want to make a heroku deploy with my own gems on private **Bitbucket** repository. I want to do with Oauth Cloning like Github (https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth).

This is possible with **Bitbucket**?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an open issue on atlassian's issue tracker -- so I assume it's not currently possible.

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7735/allow-http-access-to-repositories-via